# Templates with different parameters

Tags: c++, templates, optional-parameters, c++03

I can't find a way to turn the following templates into only one with the same effect. My goal is to instanciate a subclass of a Form. Subclasses can have constructors with none to two parameters.

```
template<class T> bool Session::OpenForm() {
    Form* form = new T();
    return OpenForm(form);
}

template<class T, class U> bool Session::OpenForm(U parameter) {
    Form* form = new T(parameter);
    return OpenForm(form);
}

template<class T, class U, class V> bool Session::OpenForm(U parameter1, V parameter2) {
    Form* form = new T(parameter1, parameter2);
    return OpenForm(form);
}
```

I use those templates like this :

```
session->OpenForm<SubForm>();
session->OpenForm<OtherSubForm>("Title");
```

Looking around i thought using optional parameters could do the trick but i can't make it working. I tried things like this :

```
template<class T, class U = T, class V = T> 
bool Session::OpenForm(U parameter1 = NULL, V parameter2 = NULL) {
    Form* form = NULL;

    if(parameter2 != NULL) form = new T(parameter1, parameter2);
    else if(parameter1 != NULL) form = new T(parameter1);
    else form = new T();
}
```

Is there a way to have only one template to take care of that ? Or maybe just a better way ?

I use C++03.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with 3 overloads?  Also `(U parameter1 = NULL, V parameter2 = NULL)` looks ugly IMHO.  `NULL` should only be used for pointer types.  If they are not pointers `NULL` doesn't make much sense, even if it does compile.  Remember you can always call the more parameter function(s) from the less parameter function(s) to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Of course in C++ (ie. the current standard) one would use a variadic template. So this is really a non-problem for anybody using C++11 are and higher.

Comment: 3 overloads are fine but i'm afraid of more coming later. The parameters are indeed pointers in this case. I guess i'll stick with my solution at least until I have access to C++11. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to *technically* answer your question, but not solve the crux of it --- what you really want is variadic templates, which is a C++11 feature.

Instead, you can put all the work on the implementor of each additional SubForm type: each new SubForm class must have a constructor that accepts an *args* struct that the SubForm can use to initialize itself.

For example:

```
struct SubFormArgs{};
struct OtherSubFormArgs{
    OtherSubFormArgs(std::string s) : param1(s){}
    std::string param1;
};

struct Form{};

struct SubForm : Form{
    SubForm(SubFormArgs){}
};

struct OtherSubForm : Form{
    OtherSubForm(OtherSubFormArgs args): myStr(args.param1){}
    std::string myStr;
}
```

`SubForm` uses `SubFormArgs` to construct itself, and `OtherSubForm` uses `OtherSubFormArgs` to construct itself.

This simplifies your `OpenForm` function like so:

```
bool OpenForm(Form* f){/*...*/}

struct Session
{
    template<class T, class U>
    bool OpenForm(U ctor_params)
    {
        Form* form = new T(ctor_params);
        return ::OpenForm(form);
    }
};
```

And a test:

```
Session* session = new Session();
session->OpenForm<SubForm>(SubFormArgs());
session->OpenForm<OtherSubForm>(OtherSubFormArgs("Title"));
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/49ly90ljvb8H6gn7)

Comment: Very informative, thank you ! I think i'll stick with my multiple templates for now and get back when i have access to C++11 :)